# Return other value if key not found in the map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have `unordered map`:

```
static unordered_map<int, long> my_map;
auto& result = my_map[i];
```

If there is no key `i`, result would be `0`. 
Is it possible to return other value, for example `NULL` or `-MAXINT`?

Comment: Use `my_map.find(i)` and compare with `my_map.end()` ?

Comment: `NULL` is the same as `0`.

Comment: This feature should be in the STL

Answer (score 4):

You may do something like (doesn't insert value in map):

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
Value& get_or(std::unordered_map<Key, Value>& m, const Key& key, Value& default_value)
{
    auto it = m.find(key);
    if (it == m.end()) {
        return default_value;
    }
    return it->second;
}
```

Or if you want to add the value in map if not present:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename T>
Value& get_or(std::unordered_map<Key, Value>& m, const Key& key, T&& default_value)
{
    return m.emplace(key, std::forward<T>(default_value)).first->second;
}
```

And use it

```
int default_value = 42;
auto& result = get_or(my_map, i, default_value);
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So you do 2 look-up.

Comment: Yep - in this context where you want to use a pre-extant value, good solution. Worth taking universal refs for key and value though?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `Key` is `const` anyway, and so that way, braced initializer list can be used. For non-const version which return reference, I have to take reference default value to avoid dangling reference.

Comment: Okay yep again makes sense. Sorry for bothering you :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: with `insert`, I can use `T&&` for default value :-)

Comment: Just spotted that the two functions actually do different things. Intentional?

Answer (score 2):

The result `0` does not signify "the value was not found". The value *was* found: the `[]` operation has just added it. The result is `0` because that is the default value for `long`, and your `[]` operation *default constructed* the `long`. And you cannot change how `long` is default constructed.

If you want to just see whether the element already exists, you should be using [`my_map.count(i)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/count), which returns `1` or `0`, meaning "this key exists" and "this key does not exist" respectively. If the key does not exist, you can then add one with whatever value you like using [`my_map.insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert).

Answer (score 2):

when you use `my_map[i]` if the value doesn't exist, it is created. So you can create anything differently to ts default constructor. Or for the `long` its default value. You have a couple of options:

Set the value to what you want if it doesnt exist:

```
if (my_map.find(i) == my_map.end()) {
    my_map[i] = MAX_INT; //Or whatever you want.
}
```

Or have your own wrapper class for `long` with a default constructor:

```
struct DefLong {
  long myLong;
  long& operator() {
      return myLong;
  }
  DefLong () : myLong(MAX_INT){}
}
....
static unordered_map<int, DefLong> my_map;
auto& result = my_map[i];
long otheresult = my_map[i];
```